# Does azure storage operational backup automatically restore data to secondary region after restoration to Primary region

Tags: azure-blob-storage, blob, azure-storage, restore, azure-backup-vault

I wanted to restore storage account using ops backup restore point. If the restore completed to primary region then it will automatically restore to secondary region as well or we need to restore again to secondary region ?

Comment: It appears that Azure Storage offers account failover for geo-redundant storage accounts based on the papers that were retrieved[1]. Your storage account is set up in the new primary region to be locally redundant when you fail over from the primary to the secondary region. The account in the new primary region can then be configured for geo-redundancy. After a failover, the new primary region starts transferring data to the new secondary area, which was the primary before the initial failover, as soon as the account is set up for geo-redundancy.

Comment: However, it can take some time before the new secondary receives a complete copy of the new primary's data.[1](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/storage/common/storage-disaster-recovery-guidance.md)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Azure Storage supports account failover for geo-redundant storage accounts With Disaster recovery and storage account [failover](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/storage/common/storage-disaster-recovery-guidance.md) but Data is not moved outside of the source and target regions that you have selected via Azure Site Recovery. The secondary region will not immediately be restored if you restore the storage container backup to the primary region.

- Disaster recovery and storage account failover:

```
az storage account show \ --name accountName \ --expand geoReplicationStats
```

[image]

```
az storage account failover \ --name accountName
```

[image]

- Choose the right redundancy option
- Design for high availability

```cs
 BlobContainerClient? containerClient = null;

    BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);

    CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = source.Token;

    
    string containerName = $"container-{Guid.NewGuid()}";

    Console.WriteLine("\nCreating container");
    containerClient = await blobServiceClient.CreateBlobContainerAsync(containerName, PublicAccessType.None, null, cancellationToken);

    if (await containerClient.ExistsAsync())
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Created container {containerClient.Name}\n");
    }

 
    BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);

  
    Console.WriteLine($"\nUploading blob: {blobName}");
    await blobClient.UploadAsync(BinaryData.FromString("If at first you don't succeed, hopefully you have a good retry policy.").ToStream(), overwrite: true);
```

[image]

- For more details refer this [MSDOC](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/storage/common/storage-disaster-recovery-guidance.md) for storage  account failover.

Comment: Hi , Not looking for failover but regarding backup restore. If would like to restore the backup for storage container then it will also restore for secondary region as well ?

Comment: hi@samraj Refer [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/storage/common/storage-disaster-recovery-guidance.md) para  `Choose the right redundancy option`  for  [secondary region](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/storage/common/storage-redundancy.md)

Comment: For geo-redundant storage accounts, Azure Storage provides account failover, according to the documents that were retrieved. Your storage account is set up in the new primary region to be locally redundant when you failover from the primary to the secondary region. The account in the new primary region can then be configured for geo-redundancy. After a failover, the new primary region starts transferring data to the new secondary area, which was the primary before the initial failover, as soon as the account is set up for geo-redundancy.

Comment: Before the new secondary receives a complete copy of the new primary's data, though, it can take some time. Whether or not the restoration to the secondary region is automatic cannot be determined from the [documents](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/storage/common/storage-disaster-recovery-guidance.md) that were recovered.

Comment: The new primary region, which was the primary before the initial failover, immediately started transferring data to the new secondary region following a failover, it is noted. for more details refer to this [MSDOC](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/storage/common/storage-disaster-recovery-guidance.md)